# Using CircledImageView in android wear

Tags: android, android-layout, wear-os

I am using the `CircledImageView` to display the image in the `ListView`, but I am not getting the image view as circular. Can anyone tell me how to achieve this?

Comment: Can you show your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok got it woking by setting the height and width as wrap content and also providig the radius of the cirlce.

Here is the code working for me.

```
 <android.support.wearable.view.CircledImageView
        android:id="@+id/im_action_icons"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        app:circle_border_color="#FFFFFFFF"
        app:circle_border_width="2dp"
        app:circle_color="@color/blue"
        app:circle_radius="23dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this short code it works for me:

```
RoundedBitmapDrawable roundedBitmapDrawable = RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(Activity.this.getResources(), yourbitmap);
roundedBitmapDrawable.setCircular(true);
your imageview.setImageDrawable(roundedBitmapDrawable);
```

If you use [Glide library](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) to download images you can do something like this.

```
Glide.with(context).load(your image url).asBitmap().placeholder(your default place holder).error(error place holder).into(new BitmapImageViewTarget(your imageview) {
        @Override
        protected void setResource(Bitmap resource) {
            super.setResource(resource);
            RoundedBitmapDrawable roundedBitmapDrawable = RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(Activity.this.getResources(), resource);
            roundedBitmapDrawable.setCircular(true);
            your imageview.setImageDrawable(roundedBitmapDrawable);
        }
    });
```

You can also do these thing with [Picasso library](http://square.github.io/picasso/)